# Array as argument of a function in Bash: only first element get returned

Tags: arrays, bash, function, shell

I found a script written in Bash that automate the installation of packages and software on a new Mac.

This is part of the script:

```
# helpers
function echo_ok() { echo -e '\033[1;32m'"$1"'\033[0m'; }

PACKAGES=(
    vim
    zsh
    tree
    git
)

echo_ok "Installing packages..." 
brew install "${PACKAGES[@]}"
```

The script correctly install all of the packages listed in the array.

For testing purpose, I modified the line

```
brew install "${PACKAGES[@]}"
```

into

```
echo_ok "${PACKAGES[@]}"
```

As output I get only the first item of the array (`vim`).

However, if I use

```
echo "${PACKAGES[@]}"
```

I get all the elements of the array.

It looks like the problem is passing the array in the helper function.
If I'm not mistaken, `'\033[1;32m'` and `'\033[0m';` have to do with the colours of the text and `"$1"` is the parameter passed into that helper function. Are the double quotes important? Because I see double quote also around `"${PACKAGES[@]}"`.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong and why I'm not getting the entire content of the array as when used with `brew install "${PACKAGES[@]}"`.

Comment: `"$1"` should be `"$@"` in `echo_ok()`

Comment: @Inian: That is not the only issue as `echo -e` with `$@` will not print each element with newline

Comment: I don't see OP's intentions being wanting to print it on new line. They seem to be testing the arguments to `brew install` in which case the arguments need to be on the same line

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to this i.e. `printf` instead of `echo -e` and use `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` like this:

```sh
echo_ok() {
   printf '\033[1;32m%s\033[0m\n' "$@"
}
```